# Simple CSS border, dynamically changing height to that of parent element

Tags: css, border

I have a `div` which holds two floating `div`s side by side. I want these two floating `div`s to have a `1px solid #e7e7e7;` border separating them. I have tried putting `border-right: ...` on the first child `div`, but then when the second `div` is taller, the border doesn't extend to the full height (it stays at its local height). The content in both `div`s are dynamic so it needs to either adjust to the parent `div`'s height or to take on the maximum height between itself and its sibling.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eW7Rr/ ?

Comment: I like the idea, but the idea of manipulating the padding and margin is not only inelegant, but counter-intuitive if my div will have dynamic content (which could go well over 500px). Not only that but I will be using bottom padding on the child divs for extra styling so it's not a very feasible suggestion.

Comment: Inelegant maybe but you're looking to do something without JavaScript that isn't easy to do. Good luck.

Comment: Almost forgot about using display:table-cell. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eW7Rr/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JavaScript, the only other way I know of would be to use tables, with a border on one of the cells.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using jQuery? You can use a simple query like this to do what you want to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var leftDivHeight = $(".leftDiv").height();
    var rightDivHeight = $(".rightDiv").height();

    if(leftDivHeight < rightDivHeight){
        $(".leftDiv").height(rightDivHeight);
    }
    else {
        $(".rightDiv").height(leftDivHeight);
    }
});
```

Comment: The question doesn't mention, and isn't tagged with either JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: I know it isn't, but it's a solution nonetheless, but unless I'm not thinking properly there isn't a way to dynamically change a div's height based on the height of another div. Hence the usage of jQuery...

Comment: Maybe not when you think of it that way, but it seems possible if you think of it as inheriting its parent's height. I can use jQuery, but I'd rather leave this to CSS.

Comment: Very true. Does your parent div have a fixed height and the child divs have a 100% height?

Comment: Parent does not have a fixed height, no, but I can set the nested divs to have `100%`

Comment: Does this help any? http://jsfiddle.net/3wv5A/

If you set the parent to a fixed height and set the children to have 100% height, that should fix your problem. Unfortunately, "min-height" won't work for the parent div, only "height"